# how to change dynamically created div's background with on click JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm adding and removing div's from the 'main' tag using the two buttons i created. i want to change each of the div's backgroud color on click but nothing works....why is that??

this is my code

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
        </header>

        <div id="buttonscontainer">
            <button class="button" id="add">+</button>  
            <button class="button" id="remove">-</button>   
        </div>

        <main id="main">
        </main>
    </div>      
</body>
```

script:

```
window.onload=function(){
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
            var rectangle = '<div class="rect"></div>';
            document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += rectangle;
        }
    document.getElementById("add").onclick = addRect;
    document.getElementById("remove").onclick = removeRect;
    }

/*defines the behaviour of the addRect onclick*/
 function addRect(){
     var rectangle = '<div class="rect"></div>';
     document.getElementById("main").innerHTML += rectangle;
 }

 /*defines the behaviour of the removeRect onclick*/
 function removeRect(){
     var rectangle = '<div class="rect"></div>';
     document.getElementById("main").lastChild.remove();
 }
```

Comment: Where's the code you used for changing background color?

Comment: If you don't show us the JavaScript, how are we supposed to help you correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you have already, you can do this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    for(var i=0;i<6;i++){
        //just make use of addRect here, no need to duplicate code
        addRect();
    }
}

//Update addRect to add elements in a more DOM like manner,
//so we don't clear previously bound events
function addRect(){
    var rectangle = document.createElement('div');
    rectangle.className = 'rect';
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(rectangle);
    document.getElementById("main").lastChild.onclick = changeColour;
}

function changeColour() {
    this.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y4L1dpxx/)

Comment: i tried something similar but it will only allow me to change the background of the last child, but what i need is to be able to change each of the div's background when clicking on it

Comment: @Adam I missed your initial `for` loop - will edit, but this should allow clicking on any of the divs, not just the last child.  We're simply binding to the `click` event of the last child at the time of creation, rather than it only _ever_ working on the last child

Comment: @Adam Apologies.  Seems that setting things via `innerHTML` clears all the previously bound event handlers, so this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You have no css in the code. how do you wish to change the bg color?
The code works, you are adding zero height rects. 
You should use the chrome dev tools in order  to see the changes..

Comment: I dont think css has anything to do with my question but here's the class css if it helps..:.rect{
 width: 420px;
 height: 200px;
 background: #ffffff;
 border: 1px solid;
 float: left;
 margin-left: 56px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

Comment: I meant that I don't see the part in which you are changing the rect color. I didn't understand that you don't have it.